# Mono: runtime error: v4.0.30319

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I have a big problem with Mono; constantly receiving this error message.

> WARNING: The runtime version Supported by This application is unavailable. Using default runtime: v4.0.30319

I have reinstalled the server three times already, but new installs unfortunately always have the same problem.

- OS: Debian 7 mini
- Mono: full instaled (mono-complet up to date)
- PROCON: 1.4.0.6
- Link: [PROCON usage on Debian 7](https://forum.myrcon.com/showthread.php?4209-HowTo-Run-a-PRoCon-Layer-%281-4-0-6%29-with-Linux-mono)

Comment: It looks like the application was built against a different (newer) version of the runtime. What are your build settings?

Comment: @ChrisF it should be an older version such as 2.0. 4.0.30319 is already the latest.

Answer (score 2):

If the application starts normally and you only want to suppress the warning, there are two options:

## Configuration file

Add the configuration file to the directory where the binary is located, with the name `<binary-name>.config`, e.g. for `application.exe` use `application.exe.config`.

The contents of the file should be as following. Of course, the comment is optional.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Add this file to the legacy .NET application folder to prevent:
WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable. -->
<configuration>
    <startup>
            <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
            <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup> 
</configuration>
```

#### Sources

- http://do-the-right-things.blogspot.cz/2017/05/the-way-to-suppress-monos-warning.html
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/#application-configuration-files

## Command line

Specify the runtime manually when launching the application.

```
mono --runtime=v4.0 application.exe
```

#### Sources

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/mono
- [Mono on MacOSX - "The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable." v4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508922/mono-on-macosx-the-runtime-version-supported-by-this-application-is-unavailab)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a dissembler to check the assemblies you should see which CLR version they were built against. My guess is that they were built against 2.0.

Mono 4 removes the old 2.0 CLR and 4.0 CLR (in fact 4.5 profile) becomes the default and the only. So this is simply a warning, not an error.