# Unable To Compile Google Protobuf 2 Messages using C# with Mono

Tags: c#, mono, protocol-buffers, protobuf-csharp-port

i am using protobuf and c#, and the [c# port](https://github.com/jskeet/protobuf-csharp-port) seems to be the answer for generating c# classes using proto2.  i was able to figure out that the c# port was built with dotnet 2.0 from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33517383/1438908), and i am using mono latest, which is 4.4.x at the time of writing.  my command is:

```
mono ./ProtoGen.exe --proto_path=../idl -output_directory=../out ../my.proto
```

it yields

```
WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
Using default runtime: v4.0.30319
```

no files are output, and `echo $?` tells me it exited with `255`.

any tips?  thanks!

Comment: Can not say anything about that "legacy" version, but I use the newest protobuf with C# output : https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases (see c# section)

Comment: Ya, v3 is explicitly not compatible w/ v2

Answer (score 0):

It is a little buried in the current protobuf v3.0 [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp-generated), however, it is there under the **Compiler Invocation** section.

Only proto3 messages are supported by the C# code generator. Ensure that each .proto file begins with a declaration of:

```
syntax = "proto3";
```

Comment: thanks jake, however, per the title of the issue and the description, I am explicitly targeting protobuf 2.